# Android Studio: TextInputLayout para escribir dirección IP

Tags: android, android-studio

En un campo `TextInputLayout` donde se introducirá una dirección IP con el siguiente formato `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` donde `xxx` será un entero.

Pero lo que quiero es que el teclado que se muestre únicamente acepte dígitos y el signo `.`

He probado con el siguiente código en el layout, pero me muestra el teclado normal.

```
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/marco3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,."
                    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|number"
                    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/Error">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/cmpRedTienda"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="dirección de red"/>
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar lo siguiente, yo utilizo el valor android:inputType="number" en un EditText para que me levante el teclado numerico

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/marco3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/campo_numero_ip"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,."
    android:inputType="number"
    android:singleLine="true" 
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/Error"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```